# system verilog assertion trigger==1 4 cycles before signal asserted

Tags: system-verilog, assertions, system-verilog-assertions

How would I write SVA that checks that if sig goes high trigger was high 4 cycles before `trigger [*4] |-> signal`
is not good enough because it does not check that signal didn't go high for 3 cycles. Should I use `$past`  how ??

Answer (score 1):

This would check that on a rising edge of `sig`, `trigger` was high 4 clk cycles ago:

```
assert_name: assert property (
   @(posedge clk) (
     ($rose(sig) -> $past(trigger,4))
   )
);
```

Comment: but I don't think this checks that trigger was high for 4 **consecutive** cycles before sig rose ? which is what I need. so maybe `|->($past(trigger,4) & $past(trigger, 3) )`... ?

Comment: @Meir your correct this only check it was high 4 clks ago. You can then check it was high for 4 clks from that point.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing stopping you writing a small piece of synthesisable RTL which counts how many cycles `trigger` has been high.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (trigger) begin
        triggerCount := triggerCount + 1;
    end else begin
        triggerCount := 0;
    end
end

assert_name: assert property (
   @(posedge clk) (
     ($rose(sig) -> triggerCount == 4)
   )
);
```